# Converse of theorem of two tangent circles

Tags: geometry, contest-math, circles, triangles

I saw a theorem (which is true):

> Let $P$ and $Q$ be the centers of two tangent circles. Draw a line from a point through the intersection of the two circles and let that line intersect the circles at $B$ and $C$. Then $BP$ is parallel to $CQ$.

Proof:

> Angles BAP and CAQ are vertical
>   and hence equal. Triangles BAP and CAQ are isosceles
>   with equal base angles at A. The other pair of the base
>   angles are also equal. I.e., ∠ABP = ∠ ACQ. These two angles are internal to the lines BP and CQ and transversal BC. Since the internal angles are equal, the lines are parallel: PB || QC. (Source: [here](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Outline/Geometry/TwoTouchingCircles.shtml#solution))

What can I say about the converse? i.e. **if $PB || QC$ then the circles are tangent.** Is that true?

I appreciate all help.

Comment: What exactly _is_ the converse statement? Which line are you going to draw to construct $B$ and $C$?

Comment: @Arthur if PB||QC then the circles are tangent. Is that true?

Comment: I can read (most times, at least). I know that that's what you're asking. I'm asking you to tell me what the points $B$ and $C$ are, if we're not already assuming that the circles are tangent. State the _entire_ problem that you're interested in, because at the moment I can't really make sense of it.

Comment: @Arthur http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ATheoremAboutTwoTangentCircles/

Comment: There are diagrams about it here...

Comment: Wait... Sorry, I didn't state my question correctly... Let me edit it first

Comment: And that link is cool. That's for the original problem. You're asking about the converse, which seems to me to be something along the lines of "Take two circles with centers at $P$ and $Q$. Draw a line (where?) and let the line intersect the circles at $B$ and $C$ (there may be two, or no points of intersection for each circle; how do you handle that?). Then if $PB||QC$, are the circles tangent?" Can you please _state the entire problem_, because I can't make sense of this.

Comment: @Arthur actually I'm doing another problem which I *think* that I can use this to prove it... Or can you just help me with that problem and see if I can use this to prove it? Thank you

Comment: I see the flaw in this question. It makes no sense... Sorry